# Rails / JQuery Mobile: DELETE method not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I have code that outputs to identical HTML on my main site to my mobile site. On the mobile site only, clicking the link sends a GET request rather than DELETE. The only difference is that the mobile site is running JQuery Mobile.

Here's the output HTML on the main site:

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Logout</a>
```

Here's the output HTML on the mobile site:

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" data-ajax="false" rel="nofollow" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Log Out</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to add to my manifest file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

This is used by rails to make "link_to method: :DELETE" tags work.